# .htaccess regex

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I'm a real beginner with regex. I think I *NEARLY* understand this, but having spent a day and a half on it, I can't quite get it right.

At the moment my OLD domain has this rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/sheepdog\-training\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

That successfully redirects every page on the old site to the exact same file on the new site (sheepdog-training.com). Unfortunately, I need it to redirect to two new sites.

I need all files which begin with /tb- to go to: sheepdog-training.com and I need (nearly) all the remaining files to go to: theworkingsheepdog.com.

The exceptions are: contact and main-menu.

My web hosting company says I should do a separate 301 redirect for every page and post on the website, but there are hundreds of them! I'm sure what I'm looking for is possible with regex. Can you help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to have multiple RewriteRules (remember that the rewrite conditions apply to the rule that immediately follows them thought).

Also remember: `You should avoid using .htaccess files completely if you have access to httpd main server config file. Using .htaccess files slows down your Apache http server. Any directive that you can include in a .htaccess file is better set in a Directory block, as it will have the same effect with better performance.`. See here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html

```
RewriteRule ^/tb-(.*)$ "http\:\/\/sheepdog\-training\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\/theworkingsheepdog\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Something like this should redirect all the paths starting with `/tb-` to the same path (except for the `/tb-` part) to the sheepdog-training site. And the other rule should redirect all the other URLs to the workingsheepdog site. If the first rule matches, the rule processing stops, so order of these two rules is important.

Configs are not tested by me, but should require only small modifications if any in case they do not work.

Comment: I wouldn't know how (or dare) to access the main server config file! Slowing down the server shouldn't matter too much as these links will all be removed fairly soon.
The configs seem to work (thanks) but I really wanted the "tb-" included in the destination filename. (I did say "exact same files").

Comment: To include the `/tb-` simply wrap it with the capturing group: `RewriteRule ^/(tb-.*)$ "http\:\/\/sheepdog\-training\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]`

Comment: Of course! Thanks so much. I realised I don't need rules for main-menu and contact because they're included in the second rule.

Comment: You are welcome :) . Consider accepting the answer if it was helpful.